# WVGA apps on 1024 X 600 resolution

Tags: android

Is there any way to scale down 1024 X 600 resolution to 480 X 800, I am developing an app for WVGA resolution but i have a tablet only how can i scale down tablet resolution, Please guide i want it to run perfectly on WVGA resolution

Answer (score 0):

> Please guide. I want it to run perfectly on WVGA resolution.

If you want it to run perfectly on WVGA resolution, then you probably shouldn't be using a tablet as your primary testing device. You should use the emulator to guarantee a realistic testing environment.

I also suggest you consult the [**Supporting Multiple Screens**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) article on the Android Developers site before you decide to restrict your application to a single screen size.